# Android System WebView actualizado no permite redireccion

Tags: android, webview

Buenas a todos!!! Tengo una app que trabaja con un webview y a partir de la ultima actualizacion de Android System WebView, dejaron de funcionar los links que tengo hechos en javascript, por ejemplo:

```
window.location='index.php';
```

el resto de las funciones de javascript funciona bien, pero no redirecciona, en lugar de hacerlo , solo refresca la pagina.
Y este es el codigo de mi Activity

```
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(getChromeClient());

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadData("HTML", "text/html", "utf-8");

    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

Alguien sabrá cual es el error. Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Comment: Hey Zitiapp Web, bienvenido!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta te recomiendo para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Comment: "a partir de la ultima actualizacion" ¿A que actualización te refieres? que sistema operativo?

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys por responder en este momento estoy con un problema del cual ya llevo varios días sin encontrar solución. Con respecto a tu pregunta de a que actualización me refería, es sobre el Complemento Android System WebView que nació con Lollipop. Mi App funcionaba perfectamente hace varios meses ya, y hace unos días cuando actualicé dicho complemento desde Play Store, empezaron a fallar las redirecciones que mencionaba. Cuando desinstalo las actualizaciones todo vuelve a funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: Puedes darme el url de lo que comentas, te refieres a esto: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=es

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, ya resolvi el problema, en el metodo shouldOverrideUrlLoading el return estaba en false. lo cambie a true y funcionó..